# Lightweight Replacement for System.Data.DataTable

Tags: c#, data-structures, .net-4.0

There is tabular data that is being stored in the database as a delimited data.  Not ideal, I know, but that's how the system was designed.  I need to pull the data out and parse it into some kind of structure.

In the old days, I'd use a DataTable and call it good.  Now, however, that just feels dirty.  What is a better, more efficient, and more lightweight structure to store tabular data in my data model?

Comment: The two choices I have in mind are IList<Tuple<>> and IList<IList<>>.  We have it limited to six columns, so I don't need anything beyond 6 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just create a class that has all the columns of the database as properties. Then just instantiate an implementation of ICollection (List, Hashset, etc..) and fill it (using LINQ for example).

```
  public class Customer
  {
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Customer(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
  }
```

And do something like:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
using (DbDataReader reader = // instantiate reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       Customer customer = new Customer(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
       customers.Add(customer);
    }
}
```

If you are accessing data that is stored in a database you may want to look at LinqToSql or LinqToEntities.

Comment: I am using fluent nhibernate.  This tabular data is stored as a delimited string in a single field in the database.  I need to parse it out of the string and into an object.

Comment: Then just implement your algorithm to extract the data, create a class with the properties you need and fill a ICollection<T>! :)

Comment: I would disagree that it can be an answer. Because, if you already know the Data Structure with column names and data types of the column names at the COMPILE TIME, then yes, obviously you can create a class for your own table, which is trivial. But, for example, if I let my user choose a CSV file and I do not know the header of the CSV file, then in order to hold that CSV file content in the memory in a proper data structure, I see DataTable is an option, because I can store the Column Name and Column DataType into the DataTable. I was looking for a lightweight alternative to DataTable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a lightweight DataTable from one of the Telerik developers:

http://blogs.telerik.com/vladimirenchev/posts/09-04-23/lightweight-datatable-for-your-silverlight-applications.aspx

It supports INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged so it works well for data binding.

I wouldn't say it's any less "dirty", but it is an alternative.

Comment: Why use a DataTable that needs also an external library? Collections in .NET work so well...

Comment: @AS-CII - I mention it only as an alternative that behaves more like a System.Data.DataTable. You can avoid the external assembly by compiling into your own.

Answer (score 0):

Well use a library i developed it include type to type convert and many more, and datareader to list 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Generic.LightDataTable/